# Accessing super class object

Tags: java, class, variables, extends, super

So I have this class:

```
public class ServiceClass {

    public static Validator validator;

    public ServiceClass() {

        if (validator == null) validator = new Validator();
    }
}
```

Now I have an extended class:

```
public class Service1 extends ServiceClass {

    public Service1() {

        validator.init();
    }
}
```

Is that the right way to access the validator object? Do I have to create get ans set methods on super class? Should I use super.validator.init(); ?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: since `validator` is declared to be static, this might cause troubles if it calls the `init` method twice, depending on what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use getter and setter, since they allow you to control the access way better than directly accessing the element.

Apart from that, yes, that is correct.

Also: note that you use validator as "static", that means every object of `ServiceClass` or any child will share the same object (they won't have each an object of that class), so be careful with your what you do with that.